# Jenkins auto build is not working

Tags: jenkins

This is ramesh,
I tried to build my .net application using jenkins, my source is reside at in github. I can get build, when using manual build option in  jenkins. But auto build is not working, when i give commit on github.

Thanks

Comment: And how have you configured scm polling/monitoring?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. What are you Build triggers?

Here's what I use:

[image]

Jenkins uses something called corn expressions

MINUTES Minutes in one hour (0-59)

HOURS Hours in one day (0-23)

DAYMONTH Day in a month (1-31)

MONTH Month in a year (1-12)

DAYWEEK Day of the week (0-7) where 0 and 7 are Sunday

```
* */23 * * * == one day
```